# Error while comparing a vector with the number 0.7

Tags: r

it's mi first question
Im having trouble when comparing an array, colum value, etc with number 0.7 in R
I've found some questions which includes this value, but not related to this apparet "bug"

As example

```
f<-(1:9)*0.1

f==0.8
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#or 
which(f==0.8)
#[1] 8

#as expected, but when it's 0.7 
f==0.7
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

which(f==0.7)
#integer(0)
```

Although it can be 'solved' quoting the value ...

```
which(f=='0.7')
#[1] 7
```

may it be a bug?

Comment: Although it prints as 0.7, it's actually 0.699999... or 0.7000...1. See the linked question for more information.

Comment: found this: `0.7 - 7*0.1` = -1.110223e-16